# Direction of two points

Tags: math, vector, vector-graphics, vectorization

Some high school math concept has been forgotten, so I ask here.

If I have two points `p1(x1,y1)`, `p2(x2,y2)`, the direction is `P1-->p2`, that's `p1` points to `p2`. To represent this direction by vector, is it `Vector(x2-x1,y2-y1)` or `Vector(x1-x2, y1-y2)`?

By the way, what is the purpose to normalize a vector?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

- Answer 1: it is `Vector(x2-x1,y2-y1)`
- Answer 2: Normalizing means to scale the vector so that its length is 1. It is a useful operation in many computations, for example, normal vectors should be specified normalized for lighting calculations in computer graphics. The normalized vector  of `v(x,y)` is `vn(x/Length(v), y/length(v))`.

HTH

Answer (score 41):

A nice way to remember which way the subtraction goes is to think of what the vector actually does. Imagine vector v resting at p1, pointing and connecting to p2. This means that p1 + v = p2. Therefore, v = p2-p1.