# How to make gravity to center in Libgdx with box2d

Tags: android, libgdx, box2d, gravity

How can I set gravity to any body or the center of the screen? I am curious about the logic behind it.

I have two circle bodies: aBody, which is a static body, and bBody, which is dynamic. The world has gravity set to (0, 0).

I want it to resemble the image in the link:
[image: Image Link]

Comment: I guess you have to add a force towards the center to every body in every tick, as the force direction depends on the current position.

Comment: @Springrbua You are right but how ? :/

Comment: First calculate the normalized `Vector` between the two points. Read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483937/direction-of-two-points) how to do that. Then add a `force` to the body, using this `Vector`, multiplied with the forces strenght. You can read how to do this [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Box2d)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you have to do is to apply a force that will simulate gravity with center of screen (let's imagine that in the center there is very very heavy object that will be pulling other objects).

The equation is well known and easy to implement - [look here to read about it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity#Newton.27s_theory_of_gravitation).

Having equation you just have to implement it like:

```
Body body, centerBody;
Vector2 center = new Vector2(0, 0);
...

//in render method
float G = 1; //modifier of gravity value - you can make it bigger to have stronger gravity

float distance = body.getPosition().dst( center ); 
float forceValue = G / (distance * distance);

// Vector2 direction = center.sub( body.getPosition() ) );
// Due to the comment below it seems that it should be rather:
Vector2 direction = new Vector2(center.x - body.getPosition().x, center.y - body.getPosition().y);

body.applyForce( direction.scl( forceValue ), body.getWorldCenter() );
```

Of course you can modify the "center of the gravity" with modifying **center** Vector2.

Comment: I think there's a bug here: `center.sub()` modifies the center vector and returns itself for chaining as mentioned in the docs: [link](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Vector2.html#sub-float-float-)

Comment: @movAX13h you are right - `Vector2` is mutable and `sub()` method is changing it's fields - seems that instead it should be `Vector2 direction = new Vector2(center.x - body.getPosition().x, center.y - body.getPosition().y)` however I'm not sure what I meant here - `center` vector seems to not be updated by my code and there is this `centerBody` that is not used anywhere... Maybe I meant this `centerBody.getPosition` should be used instead of `center` vector and the `centerBody` would be then updated by World... more than 5 years passed and I don't remember to be honest... :) thank you anyway!

Comment: right ... You can use `center.cpy().sub(body.getPosition())` ... cpy() to get a clone of the vector object and perform actions on that.